# Apply New Fine Grained Password Policy to OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have created an organizational unit in Server 2012 using PowerShell and also I have created a fine grained password policy using PowerShell by following script:

```
New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Name test -DisplayName test -Precedence 100 -ComplexityEnabled $true -ReversibleEncryptionEnabled $false - PasswordHistoryCount 10 -MinPasswordLength 3 -MinPasswordAge 1.00:00:00 -MaxPasswordAge 100.00:00:00 -LockoutThreshold 3 -LockoutObservationWindow 0.00:05:00 -LockoutDuration 0.00:10:00
```

I want to apply the above policy in my created organizational unit which is named `"OU=HRdep,DC=ghufranataie,DC=com"` using PowerShell commands.

In the following commands `Applies To` is empty. I don't know how to set my organizational unit named `HRdep` distinguished name to fine grained password policy named `test`.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name HRdep
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Identity test
AppliesTo                   : {}
ComplexityEnabled           : True
DistinguishedName           : CN=test,CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=ghufranataie,DC=com
LockoutDuration             : 00:10:00
LockoutObservationWindow    : 00:05:00
LockoutThreshold            : 3
MaxPasswordAge              : 100.00:00:00
MinPasswordAge              : 1.00:00:00
MinPasswordLength           : 3
Name                        : test
ObjectClass                 : msDS-PasswordSettings
ObjectGUID                  : bc1a09d3-3bb6-4e94-b8a5-88ac12eb060f
PasswordHistoryCount        : 10
Precedence                  : 100
ReversibleEncryptionEnabled : False
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: How is this question different from the one you [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47986630/1630171)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fine Grained Password Policy using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986630/fine-grained-password-policy-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

You could use the ADAC to click through this type of config and the ADAC will write this code for you, which you can tweak to your needs for future use cases.
See:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/05/29/step-by-step-enabling-and-using-fine-grained-password-policies-in-ad

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/04/step-by-step-utilizing-powershell-history-viewer-in-windows-server-2012-r2

Or look to the instructions here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20806.how-to-apply-an-ad-ds-fine-grained-password-policy-on-users-under-an-organizational-unit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have not read any of the documentation on Fine-Grained Passwords, as almost every article will tell you that you cannot apply a Fine-Grained password policy directly on an Organizational Unit.

They can only be applied only to users or global security groups.

---

> PSOs cannot be applied to organizational units (OUs) directly. If your users are organized into OUs, consider creating global security groups that contain the users from these OUs and then applying the newly defined fine-grained password and account lockout policies to them. If you move a user from one OU to another, you must update user memberships in the corresponding global security groups.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx

> By default, you cannot apply a Fine-Grained password policy directly on an Organizational Unit. This is because it can be applied only on users or global security groups.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20806.how-to-apply-an-ad-ds-fine-grained-password-policy-on-users-under-an-organizational-unit.aspx

> Fine-grained password policy cannot be applied to an organizational unit (OU) directly. To apply fine-grained password policy to users of an OU, you can use a shadow group.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx